# trying to align three images in twitter bootstrap 2.3.2 row/span

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am trying to align all three images so they are centered in the row, evenly.

Here is a fiddle of the markup, http://jsfiddle.net/bkmorse/btCRk

```html
<div class="container"
    <div class="row" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <div class="span12">
            <a href="" class="share-icon facebook" title="Share on facebook">share on facebook</a>
            <a href="" class="share-icon twitter" title="Share on twitter">share on twitter</a>
            <a href="" class="share-icon email" title="Share in an email">send an email</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
a.share-icon {
    height:64px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:64px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
}

a.share-icon.facebook {
    background: #fff url('http://f.cl.ly/items/3F1o172Z1o0824021F2C/facebook.jpg') no-repeat;
}
a.share-icon.twitter {
    background: #fff url('http://f.cl.ly/items/3C3I1B0g0o0V3V1Z3i2I/twitter.jpg') no-repeat;
}
a.share-icon.email {
    background: #fff url('http://f.cl.ly/items/3E1e0o3a0s0I3G3r2X2T/email.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

I've tried text-align:center; I've tried pull-left/right. I am not having any luck. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: text-align:center for .span12 should do the trick, see this updated version http://jsfiddle.net/btCRk/6/

Answer (score 0):

text-align:center won't work for centering block elements, only inline elements. Considering you're using Twitter Bootstrap, here's 2 ways you can do this:

Option 1 - use span4s then display the links as blocks with fixed width and margin:0 auto

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <div class="span4">
            <a href="" class="share-icon facebook" title="Share on facebook">share on facebook</a>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <a href="" class="share-icon twitter" title="Share on twitter">share on twitter</a>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <a href="" class="share-icon email" title="Share in an email">send an email</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

a.share-icon {
    height:64px;
    display: block;
    width:64px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0px; }

a.share-icon.facebook { background: #fff url('http://f.cl.ly/items/3F1o172Z1o0824021F2C/facebook.jpg') no-repeat; }
a.share-icon.twitter { background: #fff url('http://f.cl.ly/items/3C3I1B0g0o0V3V1Z3i2I/twitter.jpg') no-repeat; }
a.share-icon.email { background: #fff url('http://f.cl.ly/items/3E1e0o3a0s0I3G3r2X2T/email.jpg') no-repeat; }
```

Option 2 - put the images inside the links, then have them all display inline and use text-align:center

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="border:1px solid red; text-align:center;">
        <div class="span12">
            <a href="" class="share-icon facebook" title="Share on facebook">
              <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/3F1o172Z1o0824021F2C/facebook.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
            <a href="" class="share-icon twitter" title="Share on twitter">
              <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/3C3I1B0g0o0V3V1Z3i2I/twitter.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
            <a href="" class="share-icon email" title="Share in an email">
              <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/3E1e0o3a0s0I3G3r2X2T/email.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: I apologize, I was not as clear as I should be, attached is the final result I want and I am trying to accomplish this in the 320px width view (mobile), thanks. [image]

Comment: Another way you could do this is using a list. Put the links & images in list elements, then float the li's left, and set display:table and margin: 0 auto on the ul. You'd need to clear the li's on the ul.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean or why you edited my answer rather than commenting! If you're using Twitter Bootstrap then using 3 span4 divs in a row will achieve this, as suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use the `text-center` class..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <div class="span12 text-center">
            <a href="" class="share-icon facebook" title="Share on facebook">share on facebook</a>
            <a href="" class="share-icon twitter" title="Share on twitter">share on twitter</a>
            <a href="" class="share-icon email" title="Share in an email">send an email</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: **http://bootply.com/70873**